# Steam Giving Fatal Error on Launch Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: steam

After switching from the Beta Client to the stable version, I restarted Steam and it keeps giving me an error and fails to launch:

> Couldn't set up the Steam Runtime. Are you running low on disk space?
>   Continuing...
>   (I have about 140GB of free space, so this can't be right)

I've tried completely removing and reinstalling steam, but it doesn't work. It gives me this message every time:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libXtst.so.6
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
>   libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
>   libva.so.1
>   libbz2.so.1.0
>   libvdpau.so.1
>   libva.so.1
>   libva-x11.so.1

Comment: @Terrance this had no effect on my setup

Comment: @Erik This comment was a long time ago.  And if you are having an issue that might be different then this one, ask a new question.  Make sure to add lots of detail into your question.

Comment: September is not that long ago, but I am just letting you know

Answer (score 1):

Alright, my solution was to go to ".steam" in your home directory(make sure show hidden files is checked) and move "ubuntu12_32" somewhere else, I put it in trash. Then I relaunched steam and let it update and it was fixed. Don't delete the file permanently unless it works through this method.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in terminal.  I had the exact same problem, this fixed it

```
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

Comment: didn't help my setup on Ubuntu 18.04 at all, same error